# Php Memory Error but I have adjust my php.ini in CI4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am using PHP7.4 and Ci4.19

The file I am reading is less than 14mb.  I get this following two errors;

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 157286400 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/example.com/development.example.com/app_dir/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Common.php on line 395
```

and this;

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 157286400 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/example.com/development.example.com/app_dir/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/Debug/Exceptions.php on line 154
```

In my php.ini file I have the following setting and yes I restarted apache2 after changing the settings;

```
memory_limit = 150M
post_max_size = 150M
```

Not sure what I am getting this error and how to fix it.

Her is the code;

```
public function ski_index()
{

    helper("filesystem");
                  
    // Read the JSON file      
    $json = file_get_contents(WRITEPATH.'/ski/raw_data/ski_areas.geojson');

    // Decode the JSON file to an array
    $array_data = json_decode($json,true);
     
    // for the view
    $this->data['array_data'] = $array_data;       

    // $new_array will collected filtered ski resorts by country
    $new_array = array();

    $j=1;
    foreach ($array_data['features'] as $value){
        // if isset and filter by country
        if (isset($value['properties']['location']['iso3166_1Alpha2']) && $value['properties']['location']['iso3166_1Alpha2'] == 'JP'){
            array_push($new_array, $value);
            $j++;
        }
    }
    
    // reconstruct by putting the array into FeatureCollection
    $reassemble_data = array ('type'=>'FeatureCollection', 'features'=>$new_array);
    
    // convert it back to json/geojson
    $this->data['new_array'] = json_encode($reassemble_data);     

    //write out to new file
    $file_content = $this->data['new_array'];
    if (!write_file(WRITEPATH."/ski/filtered_data/japan_ski_resorts.geojson", $file_content)){
        echo "Error - cannot write to path";
    } else {
        echo "Success - written to file";
    }
    return view('/Admin/Ski/ski_index', $this->data );
}
```

Comment: This sort of error often occurs when you're allocating elements in an array and your program loop doesn't end when it should. There are other causes. Since there's no code here we can only speculate.

Comment: Please post the related code. If you are only reading a 14MB file then I don't think there should be a problem but we can only speculate.

Comment: It's better not to alter php.ini file. Instead you can use ini_set() function.

Comment: Have added code

Comment: Filesize doesn't match in-memory size 1:1 obviously... a 14MB JSON, read & converted into an PHP array, will likely use several dozend (if not hundreds!) MB in memory.

Comment: @Honk de Hase - yes, am just reading that json to array is some 10x bigger if I understand correctly.  Wonder if there is a better way to filter my geojson?

Comment: I doubt it... you'll need to adjust the memory limit accordingly.

Comment: I tried ini_set('memory_limit', -1); but still get Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 523087872) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes).  The actual file size is 95.3MB

Comment: Seems you still have a restriction at 512MB... probably your hoster won't let you have more than that.

Comment: It is a virtual server  at vultr so I do have access to php.ini.  Doesn't seem to want to give me any more memory though.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to be more conscientious about your memory usage. Clean up your tracks behind you; when you're done with variables, unset them. Pass things by reference rather than value.

Answer (score 0):

By default, PHP variables pass by value. Does create variables to store value will have a clone of that data, these required more memory. One way to preserve memory is to avoid creating lots of variables to store the same data. Example:

```
$this->data['array_data'] = $array_data;   // Used only in view, avoid
```

See the below code for how can you use fewer unwanted variables.

```
public function ski_index()
{

helper("filesystem");
              
// Read the JSON file      
$json = file_get_contents(WRITEPATH.'/ski/raw_data/ski_areas.geojson');

// Decode the JSON file to an array
$this->data['array_data'] = json_decode($json,true);
$json = ''; // clearing memory
 
      

// $new_array will collected filtered ski resorts by country
$new_array = array();

$j=1;
foreach ($this->data['array_data']['features'] as $value){
    // if isset and filter by country
    if (isset($value['properties']['location']['iso3166_1Alpha2']) && $value['properties']['location']['iso3166_1Alpha2'] == 'JP'){
        array_push($new_array, $value);
        $j++;
    }
}


// reconstruct by putting the array into FeatureCollection & convert it back to json/geojson
$this->data['new_array'] = json_encode(array ('type'=>'FeatureCollection', 'features'=>$new_array));     

//write out to new file
if (!write_file(WRITEPATH."/ski/filtered_data/japan_ski_resorts.geojson", $this->data['new_array'])){
    echo "Error - cannot write to path";
} else {
    echo "Success - written to file";
}

// for the view

return view('/Admin/Ski/ski_index', $this->data );
}
```

Comment: It dies on this line with memory problem: $this->data['array_data'] = json_decode($json,true);

Comment: In that case, take a look at https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine

Comment: Thanks.  Took a look at that but may just change to javascript.